# How can I publish an integer and string (Int16 & String) using roslibjs?

Tags: ros, rosbridge, rosbridge-server, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

I am recently learning robotic web tools.In git has some samples. I want to publish an indeger / string message .On refreshing the browser I want to get the string message in command prompt. But In my code it is not publish anything right now. Any helps are appreciated.

I run

```
 roscore
 rostopic echo /buttons
 roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
```

I am use the following code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <script src="../include/EventEmitter2/eventemitter2.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/roslib.js"></script>

 <script>
   // Connecting to ROS
   // -----------------
   var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros();

   // If there is an error on the backend, an 'error' emit will be emitted.
   ros.on('error', function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   });

   // Find out exactly when we made a connection.
   ros.on('connection', function() {
     console.log('Connection made!');
   });

   // Create a connection to the rosbridge WebSocket server.
   ros.connect('ws://localhost:9090');

   // Publishing a Topic
   // ------------------

   // First, we create a Topic object with details of the topic's name and      message type.
   var testStr = new ROSLIB.Topic({
     ros : ros,
     name : '/buttons',
     messageType : 'std_msgs/String'
   });
   // Then we create the payload to be published. The object we pass in to ros.Message matches the 
   // fields defined in the geometry_msgs/Twist.msg definition.
   var str = new ROSLIB.Message(
         a:'hello'
    );

   // And finally, publish.
   testStr.publish(str);

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <h1></h1>
   <p></p>
   <ol>
     <li><tt>roscore</tt></li>
     <li><tt>rostopic echo /buttons</tt></li>
     <li><tt>roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch</tt></li>
   </ol>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My Doubts

1. Is it there in any problem of the syntax I used?
2. how can I publish Int16 messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65971/how-can-i-publish-an-integer-and-string-(int16-&-string)-using-roslibjs?/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have both a syntax error and a bug in your message definition. To catch syntax errors, it's useful to run the JavaScript error console your web browser provides.

```
var str = new ROSLIB.Message({
  a:'hello'
});
```

The syntax error is that you are missing brackets `{` `}` around the message data.

Secondly, you have defined your message type as `std_msgs/String` which does not have a field called `a` (see http://ros.org/doc/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html). Instead, the field is called `data`:

```
var str = new ROSLIB.Message({
  data : 'hello'
});
```

With the above change, everything should work.

To publish an `std_msgs/Int16` message, simply change your data type:

```
var testInt = new ROSLIB.Topic({
  ros : ros,
  name : '/ints',
  messageType : 'std_msgs/Int16'
});

var int = new ROSLIB.Message({
  data : 5
});

testInt.publish(int);
```

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-06-27**:
hi ... thank you very much.. I have one more doubt... how can I publish a variable as an integer message...ie var int = new ROSLIB.Message({
data : int_variable
});    instead of 5 just want to use a variable

**Comment by [Wilianson](https://answers.ros.org/users/18601/wilianson/) on 2016-11-07**:
It helps me to to publish a std_msgs/Int32, I was a little lost with this work. Thank you :D